# How can I plot the time taken on each API hit on a certain endpoint using prometheus?

Tags: java, spring-boot, prometheus

I'm trying to create some metrics in Prometheus. I want to measure how long does it take to return me the response when I hit some endpoint. So I've annotated the route with `@Timed`.

Here is my rest controller:

```
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/ping")
    @Timed(value = "ping.request.time", description = "time pIng")
    public String ping(){
        return "pIng";
    }

    @GetMapping("/pong")
    @Timed(value = "pong.request.time", description = "time pOng")
    public String pong(){
        return "pOng";
    }
}
```

But after this in `http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus` nothing appears mentioning `ping` or `pong`. But after hitting these API for at least one time, they appear. The response looks something like this:

```
...
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds summary
http_server_requests_seconds_count{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",} 2.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",} 0.5708052
http_server_requests_seconds_count{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/ping",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/ping",} 0.0085949
http_server_requests_seconds_count{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/metrics",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/metrics",} 0.1374681
http_server_requests_seconds_count{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/**",} 1.0
http_server_requests_seconds_sum{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="CLIENT_ERROR",status="404",uri="/**",} 0.0148576
# HELP http_server_requests_seconds_max  
# TYPE http_server_requests_seconds_max gauge
http_server_requests_seconds_max{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/prometheus",} 0.0508929
http_server_requests_seconds_max{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/ping",} 0.0085949
http_server_requests_seconds_max{error="none",exception="none",method="GET",outcome="SUCCESS",status="200",uri="/actuator/metrics",} 0.0
...
```

But when I try to execute this query: `rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}[5m])/rate(http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri="/ping"}[5m])`, it gives me **`Empty query result`**

I have also tried other queries such as:

- `http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}`
- `http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri="/ping"}`
  But the result is the same.

How can I plot time taken on each API hit on `/ping` using prometheus?

Here is my `prometheus.yaml` file:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.

rule_files:
# - "first_rules.yml"
# - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['127.0.0.1:9090']

  - job_name: 'spring-actuator'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS:8080'] # refer system ip address rather that localhost
```

And here is how I ran my system **`docker run -d --name=prometheus -p 9090:9090 -v C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\prometheus-test\prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml`**

Comment: Are individually parts of query return anything? Like `rate(http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}[5m])`?

Comment: @markalex No... they are not returning anything...

Comment: It should have if what you showed in the example correct. Please check that Prometheus actually gets showed metrics (by query `http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}` or just `http_server_requests_seconds_sum`). If nothing returned - check targets page, to see if your target is reachable by prometheus and is actually scraped.

Comment: @markalex I had to change the target  something like this`- targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']`... to make it scrappable...  But now, there is a new issue... Everytime I query for `http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}[5m]`, it's appending one new row to data... but it should only append new data, when I'm hitting that `/ping` endpoint... right?

Comment: I believe so. Could it be that something else is making this request? Blackbox_exporter for example.

Comment: @markalex I'm not sure... but I will ask a seperate question about it... can you please answer the question with your answer **check targets page, to see if your target is reachable by prometheus and is actually scraped.**, please.... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that Prometheus actually gets showed in question metrics: if they were present you'd get some result with your query. You can verify their presence by query `http_server_requests_seconds_sum{uri="/ping"}` or just `http_server_requests_seconds_sum`.

If nothing returned - check targets page, to see if your target is reachable by Prometheus and is actually scraped.

If target is not reachable - recheck configuration. This line

```
  - targets: ['SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS:8080'] # refer system ip address rather than localhost
```

If you are using **docker** use **`host.docker.internal`** instead.

From:

[image]

To this:

[image]